# Entering IRB line prematurely into Terminal.. How to Resolve?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am just picking up ruby and wanted to input a command into terminal put pushed the return key by accident before line was not finished.

```
irb(main):007:0> mixed = {1 => ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
irb(main):008:1*
```

of course now i get "stuck" in the 008.1 of the irb...

How do I go back and edit the code?

Comment: Also I cannot quit from here...

Comment: ^C or ^D to get back to the root level prompt. ^D *again* will exit irb, so be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things I can think of off the bat: finish entering the code on the next line, or hit ctl-c and start over.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is generally flexible regarding newlines appearing in your code. In your case you can continue your code on the next line (and eventually end it with `}`).

If you would rather correct the line, either give it the input it's waiting for (`}` in your case) and get a syntax error or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to interrupt. After doing so, you can press <kbd>↑</kbd> to edit the line and fix the mistake you made.